# Can I call a function with scope of another function?

Tags: javascript, function

See the following code:

```js
function parent(child) {
  var a = 4;
  var b = 5;
  child();
}

parent(function() {
  console.log(a + b);
})
```

Here I understandably get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined.

Is there anything I can do to change only the `parent` function so that the `console.log()` in the child function has access to `a` and `b` so that it can reference it in that way?

I know I can pass `a` and `b` into `child` as arguments, but **I'm wondering if I can somehow call the child function with the parent scope injected into it so that I don't need to list the parameters in the child function.**

I also looked at `.call()`, `.apply()`, and `.bind()`, but it seemed that would only help if I wrote `this.a` and `this.b` in both `parent` AND the child function.

Comment: that doesn't exist in javascript.

Comment: If you're not passing anything into the `child` function, there's nothing passed in. It's that simple. Pass no values, get no values. This is not an Object design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `window` (by referencing `this`) to add globals to it, but this method isn't very nice, to say the least:

```js
function parent(child) {
  var a = 4;
  var b = 5;
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  child();
}

parent(function() {
  console.log(a + b);
})
```

Another ugly solution would be to use `eval`, which I do not reccomend either:

```js
function parent(child) {
  var a = 4;
  var b = 5;
  eval('var f = '+child);
  f();
}

parent(function() {
  console.log(a + b);
})
```

---

You're most likely better of passing through the variables like you mentioned above:

```js
function parent(child) {
  var a = 4;
  var b = 5;
  child(a, b);
}

parent(function(a, b) {
  console.log(a + b);
})
```

Or, you could wrap your `child` function in a wrapper function (i.e. make it a closure), which can accept parameters `a`, `b`, for your `child()` to use like so:

```js
function parent(child_wrapper) {
  var a = 4;
  var b = 5;
  var child = child_wrapper(a, b);
  child();
}

parent(function(a, b) { // wrapper function
  return function() { // original child function (untouched, just being returned by the wrapper function)
    console.log(a + b);
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for entertaining the idea and for the creative alternatives! I wholeheartedly agree that these are **not recommended** although I'd say it answers my question, that is, **no**, you cannot call a function with another function's scope.